# Fortran named operator

Tags: generics, fortran, operator-overloading, intel-fortran, named

I wrote a derived type and defined a named operator for it like this:

```
module ModuleNamedOperator
  implicit none
  type TCoords
    contains
      procedure :: TCoordsFM
      generic,public :: operator(.fm.) => TCoordsFM
  end type
  contains
    type(TCoords) function TCoordsFM(self,IVal) result(this)
      class(TCoords),intent(in) :: self
      integer(4),intent(in) :: IVal
      this=self
      write(*,'(I0)') "IVal:",IVal
    end function TCoordsFM
end module ModuleNamedOperator
```

when I tried to use it in the following codes, something weird just happened:

```
program test
  use ModuleNamedOperator
  implicit none
  type(TCoords) :: a
  integer(4) :: i
  i=1
  a=a .fm. 1              ! Case 1, valid
  a=a .fm. i              ! Case 2, valid
  a=a .fm. 1 .fm. i       ! Case 3, invalid
  a=a .fm. i .fm. 1       ! Case 4, valid
  a=a .fm. 1 .fm. 1       ! Case 5, valid
  a=a .fm. i .fm. i       ! Case 6, invalid
end program test
```

In Case 3 and Case 6, the codes are not valid. It seems that if the second argument of the operator .fm. is a variable or a named constant then something wrong would happen. So what's going on with these cases? And is there a way out? The compiler is ifort_2013_sp1.3.174 if it matters.
The compiler gives the following error message:

```
TestNamedOperator.f90(25): error #6866: Dotted string neither a defined operator nor a structure component   [FM]
  a=a .fm. 1 .fm. i
--------------^
TestNamedOperator.f90(28): error #6866: Dotted string neither a defined operator nor a structure component   [FM]
  a=a .fm. i .fm. i
--------------^
TestNamedOperator.f90(25): error #6303: The assignment operation or the binary expression operation is invalid for the data types of the two operands.
  a=a .fm. 1 .fm. i
-------------^
TestNamedOperator.f90(28): error #6303: The assignment operation or the binary expression operation is invalid for the data types of the two operands.
  a=a .fm. i .fm. i
-------------^
compilation aborted for TestNamedOperator.f90 (code 1)
```

Comment: If you mean `1`, then that isn't a named constant, but a _literal_ constant.

Comment: Why it seems? Did you receive any message?

Comment: @ Vladimir F. I have added the message.

Comment: One more thing. If I overload an intrinsic operator instead of defining a named operator, then everything is OK. For exmaple, if I declare `generic,public :: operator(>) => TCoordsFM` instead of `generic,public :: operator(.fm.) => TCoordsFM` ,then codes such as `a=a>i>1` is OK

Comment: You could try to add parenthesis to guide the compiler towards an order of execution... To me it looks like it is trying to evaluate `(i .fm. 1)`, which is not defined.

Comment: BTW: Your `write` statement is wrong...

Comment: @AlexanderVogt Yes, the `write` statement is wrong... But `a=(a.fm.i).fm.i`  or `a=((a.fm.i).fm.i)`still doesn't work.

Comment: With `ifort` 15.0.0, only cases 3 and 6 fail - weird.

Comment: Oh..Yes, Case 4 is OK while case 3 is not.. I will correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have hit an `ifort` Compiler bug, see [here](https://software.intel.com/forums/topic/358461). When changing the `write` statement to `write(*,'(A,I0)') "IVal:",IVal`, your code compiles fine with `gfortran`.

For `ifort`, calling the function explicitly helps:

```
program test
  use ModuleNamedOperator
  implicit none
  type(TCoords) :: a
  integer(4) :: i
  i=1
  a=a .fm. 1              ! Case 1, valid
  a=a .fm. i              ! Case 2, valid
  a=TCoordsFM((a .fm. 1), i)      ! Case 3, valid
  a=TCoordsFM((a .fm. i), 1)      ! Case 4, valid
  a=TCoordsFM((a .fm. 1), 1)      ! Case 5, valid
  a=TCoordsFM((a .fm. i), i)      ! Case 6, valid
end program test
```